# Mostrar un marco en el borde del documento

Tags: php, web, ms-word, phpword

¿Como mostrar un marco alrededor del documento utilizando el API de PhpWord?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En realidad es muy simple, solo se necesita agregar un estilo a la sección que contendrá todo el contenido.

```
    $style = [
        'borderBottomSize' => 1,
        'borderLeftSize' => 1,
        'borderRightSize' => 1,
        'borderTopSize' => 1
    ];

    $section = $word->addSection($style);
```